# Sum of a particular column using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Using the below mentioned query I am getting the all the values of a column called 
**promotionValue** . I want to get the sum of all the values of **matched **

```
var matched = from table1 in dvtempPropertyRoomRatePromotion.ToTable().AsEnumerable()
              join table2 in dvPropertyRooms.ToTable().AsEnumerable() on
              table1.Field<DateTime>("RateDate") equals table2.Field<DateTime>("RateDate")
            where table1.Field<DateTime>("RateDate") == table2.Field<DateTime>("RateDate")
               select table1.Field<string>("promotionValue");
```

Comment: I tried to use matched.sum(p=>p.Field<string>("promotionValue")) but for no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z.aspx) the string to `int` or `decimal`:

```
var matched = from r1 in dvtempPropertyRoomRatePromotion.ToTable().AsEnumerable()
              join r2 in dvPropertyRooms.ToTable().AsEnumerable() 
              on r1.Field<DateTime>("RateDate").Date equals r2.Field<DateTime>("RateDate").Date
              select decimal.Parse(r1.Field<string>("promotionValue"));
decimal sum = matched.Sum();
```

Note that i've also changed some other things like the redundant `where` (since you've already joined these tables) or the `Date` property of `DateTime`.

Apart from that

1. why do you need the `DataView` at all? [`ToTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ycds2f.aspx) creates always a new `DataTable`. Why don't you use `Linq-To-DataSet` for all? I assume you've used the `DataView` for filtering, use `Enumerable.Where` instead. That would be more consistent, more efficient and more readable.
2. why is the column `promotionValue` a string? You should store it as a numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

Here I m putting on simple query for sum of the two column of the different table.

SELECT 
      res.Date
      ,res.Cost
      , res.Cost+res_con.Cost
        FROM [ExpenseMst] res
        inner join [ExpenseMst_2] res_con on res_con.ID =res.ID

### Date          | cost 1 | cost 2| total

2014-03-04    | 5200    |5200   |10400

2014-03-04    | 5012    |5012   |10024

2014-03-22    |100  |100    |200

2014-03-13    |25    |25    |50

2014-02-22    | 120 |120    |240

I hope it is useful..
:)

Comment: I think he is looking for the sum over all values in a column, rather than the sum of two columns.

Answer (score -2):

you can do

```
int sum = 0;
foreach(int match in matched)
{
  sum = sum + match;
}
```